# Hibernate Validator validate set

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, dropwizard, hibernate-validator

I have custom validation annotation called `@Role` and I have custom validator which validates `User` and it works. Problem is when I want to use this validator on `Set<User>` to validate every element on this set like this

```
public class Project {
  // Validates
  @Role
  private User creator;

  // Throws error
  @Role
  private Set<User> users;
}
```

This sadly throws this error:

```
 javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'cz.studenthub.validators.annotations.Role' validating type 'java.util.Set<cz.studenthub.core.User>'
```

Is there any way to validate collections without having to write new validator for `Set<User>`?

Note: I don't want to use  `@Valid` for `User` because that instance doesn't need to be completely valid, it just needs to meet that one condition validated by my `RoleValidator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Hibernate Validator 6.0.0.Beta2 if you can.

We now have support for container element constraints so you can simply do:

```
public class Project {
    // Validates
    @Role
    private User creator;

    private Set<@Role User> users;
}
```

We are planning a Candidate Release 1 in a week so it's already pretty stable.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Dropwizard stack so updating to Beta versions is not possible, but knowing that it will be possible in near future is enough for me.